# Is there a reason why a script doesn't work on elements loaded later on?

Tags: jquery

I noticed that some jQuery buttons inside a container don't work when they are loaded after the initial page load has finished.

[For example, see this](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/again)

Those buttons on the bottom: **today**, **tomorrow**, **some other day**
work, but only at the beginning.

When you press a navigation button at the top, such as **venues**, and then click on **events** again, those buttons will no longer work. Neither do the buttons on the **search** page.

Here is the code I have, for example:

```
<a id="today_button" href="#" title="Click to show events for today"></a>



jQuery('#today_button').click(function() {   
    jQuery("#today_button").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#tomorrow_button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery("#some_other_day_button").removeClass("active");
});
```

Also, the choose buttons:

```
<a id="choose_button" href="#" title="Click to search for club events!"></a>

jQuery('#choose_button').click(function() {   

    $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('search2.html');

});
```

Thanks everybody! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamically added elements needs to be re-binded to the events

use [**`live`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) [***(deprecated)***](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/)

```
$('#choose_button').live('click', function() { ...  });
```

or [**`delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate("#choose_button","click",function(){...});
```

or [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (1.7+)

```
$(document).on("click","#choose_button",function(){...});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use delegate on `document` object for dynamic elements. Try this

```
$(document).delegate('click', 'anyValidSelector', function(){

});
```

With latest jQuery ver 1.7+ you can use `on` to attach event handlers to any element even if it is created dynamically.

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli, I took your advice and used the on function which works fine :)!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `on` event handlers if you need to attach events to dynamic HTML elements.

Where you have the following:

```
jQuery('#choose_button').click(function() {
```

try this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#choose_button', function() {
```

Comment: Nobody should be using `live()` for new code. jQuery 1.7+ you should use `on()`, older versions you should use `delegate()`.

Comment: Is `on` a drop-in replacement for `live`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the current (and not deprecated) `on` syntax